# How to make Feeds import only one post at a time when cron run?

Tags: feeds

I have a website which will import many images through Feeds. But Feeds import too much posts which affect the bandwidth.

I want Feeds import only one post at a time when cron run.

The setup:

- feeds-6.x-1.0-beta10
- Drupal 6.20

Answer (score 1):

There's no way (without hacking the Feeds module) to set this. You can affect how often the Feed updates, so if it's a feed with lots of posts set it to update more often and run cron more often, and that way fewer items will be imported per run because there won't be large amounts of new data to import each time.